# How to display all the dates between multiple two dates in a table?

Tags: mysql, join, date

I want to display all the dates between two dates for a particular record

And this is the table :

```
ID Start_Date  End_Date
-------------------------
1  2013-01-14  2013-01-18
2  2013-02-01  2013-02-04
```

and now i want to get all the dates between from date and to date.

Expected output

```
ID Date
-------------
1  2013-01-14
1  2013-01-15
1  2013-01-16
1  2013-01-17
1  2013-01-18
2  2013-02-01
2  2013-02-02
2  2013-02-03
2  2013-02-04
```

guide me to write query for that with out creating any extra tables.

I have already tried this following query

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
```

its working fine for single record. but i want get all the date intervals from my table

**Updated**

i have 6 qty of chairs for all days. So one user book 3 chars on 2013-01-14 to 2013-01-18 another person book 2 chars on 2013-01-17 to 2013-01-20. So my expected output shown below.

```
ID Date        Available
------------------------
1  2013-01-14          3
1  2013-01-15          3
1  2013-01-16          3
1  2013-01-17          5 
1  2013-01-18          5
1  2013-01-19          2
1  2013-01-20          2 
1  2013-01-21          2
```

Comment: It's look like a bad design for me. It is easy enough to check whether or not the given date belongs to the any predefined range, but it is not so reasonable to generate the whole set of possible dates. IMHO, sure.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty  my Schema http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73217

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty my expected output is given above. Available means remaining rooms

Comment: Question from the sqlfiddle, how you have `1 2013-01-14     3` , in the `property` table there are 6 rooms and in the `orders` table `(1, 1, '2013-01-14','2013-01-18',2)` for that property id `2` are booked. What is the logic of getting 3 since it does not tell the remaining `6-2`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to have a `calendar` table, defined in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
(
    a_day date PRIMARY KEY
) ;
```

... and filled with *all* the relevant dates (i.e.: all days from 1990-1-1 to 2100-12-31). For the sake of simplicity, we will fill it only with year 2013:

```
INSERT INTO 
     calendar (a_day)
VALUES
    ('2013-01-01'),
    ('2013-01-02'),
    ('2013-01-03'),
    ('2013-01-04'),
    ('2013-01-05'),
    -- everything up to
    ('2013-12-31') ;
```

At this point, you can just have a `JOIN` with the two tables; with the join condition not being an equality, but a range condition:

```
SELECT
     t.id, c.a_day
FROM
     t
     JOIN calendar c ON c.a_day BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date 
ORDER BY
     t.id, c.a_day ;
```

... and get

```
id | a_day     
-: | :---------
 1 | 2013-01-14
 1 | 2013-01-15
 1 | 2013-01-16
 1 | 2013-01-17
 1 | 2013-01-18
 2 | 2013-02-01
 2 | 2013-02-02
 2 | 2013-02-03
 2 | 2013-02-04
```

You can see all the setup at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=64c9cfdda11a97ea273cf58097594485)*

Answer (score 0):

This query uses the `date` function because column `created_at` contains both date and time.

```
SELECT date(`created_at`)
FROM table_name
WHERE date(`created_at`) BETWEEN '2018-03-08' AND '2018-03-22'
GROUP BY DATE(`created_at`)
```